# How to combine a table with one to many table into one record results

Tags: mysql

I've got a table with products:
`Insert into products (products_id, products_price) Values(1, '1.25')`

And a table with the product names

```
Insert into products_descriptions (products_id, language_id, products_name) Values (1, 1, 'shoe');
Insert into products_descriptions (products_id, language_id, products_name) Values (1, 2, 'chaussure');
```

Now I want to select the product details in one record like:
`products_id, products_price, language_id-1, products_name-1, language_id-2, products_name-2`

So the result looks like:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| products_id | products_price |  language_id-1 | products_name-1 | language_id-2 | products_name-2 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1     |      '1.25'    |        1       |      'shoe'     |          2    |   'chaussure'   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So basically I want to add the `language_id` to the `products_descriptions` column names to identify the `language` and the `products_name` and get the results in one row.

I've got stuck in solving this, so I could use some help with it.

Comment: You can't do this without dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT` might be along the lines of what you want:

```
SELECT
    p.products_id,
    p.products_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(pd.language_id, ' - ', pd.products_name)
        ORDER BY pd.language_id) AS product_names
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_descriptions pd
    ON p.products_id = pd.products_id
GROUP BY
    p.products_id,
    p.products_price;
```

**Edit:**

If you intend to consume the results of your intended query from an application, then you should be using this version:

```
SELECT
    p.products_id,
    p.products_price,
    pd.language_id,
    pd.products_name
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_descriptions pd
    ON p.products_id = pd.products_id
ORDER BY
    p.products_id,
    p.products_price;
```

Then, just iterate your result set from your application language one product at a time.

Comment: Hi Tim, 
Thank you for your response, but in this solution the language ID is added to the content (result), and not the column header name.

I'll try to make the question more clear.

Comment: @Giancarlo You _can't_ do that in MySQL, not without resorting to dynamic SQL.  My answer is reasonable assuming you don't have advanced MySQL knowledge.

Comment: Hi Tim, as the result is not easily usable, could you elaborate a bit more on the dynamic SQL?
As this sql query is initiated from a desktop application I prefer not to use a stored procedure, unless it's an absolute must.

Comment: Hi Tim, That's what I do now, but I want to solve this with the mysql query

Comment: What you are asking for is very non standard, and usually is not best practice.